# In Regular expression on linux, * refer to

Tags: linux

I'am having a doubt about * in linux system. In Regular expression on linux, “*”  refer to

I have options to it:
A)It matches the previous element zero or one time.
B)It matches the previous element one or more times
C)It matches the previous element zero or more times
D)It  matches the previous element more than once.

Comment: Please include  some code that shows why you are puzzled. As is, this looks like you have copy/pasted a job interview Q. You may want to indicate if you mean Linux cmd-line file globbing or reg-ex as used in `sed` and other languages. Good luck.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- is used to match the previous character or group zero or more times

This stands true for all forms or regex flavors out there.  From Google's RE2 to Python to Perl.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about regular expressions, or the use of * in glob patterns for tools like your shell? Regular expressions are programming language tools, not specific to Linux. I'm not sure which you're asking about, so I'll answer for both.

In regular expressions, * matches the previous expression 0 or more times.

The regex `ab*c` would match anything containing `ac`, `abc` or `abbbbbbbc`.

Glob patterns, such as those evaluated by your shell, are more complicated, but the most basic use of * is substituted 0 or more characters that are not /.

The glob pattern `/home/*/Documents` would match `/home/User1/Documents` and `/home/User2/Documents`, but not `/home/User3/backup/Documents`.